# IDN (Domain) validation with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation, idn

I want to check some domains with regular expression (regex). My old code was:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?.){0,}([a-z0-9]+([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?){1,63}(.[a-z0-9]{2,7})+$/i
```

It works but this code doesn't validate IDNs (internationalized domain names) such as öü.com or öü.öü and doesn't check "www", "http://" terms.

**My domain format is:**

- example.com

**Besides, I don't want:**

- www.example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

**Important note**: user can add the domains;

- with 2 extension like example.co.uk

Comment: Use a function that parses a URL into its constituent parts, e.g. `parse_url()`. Then check whatever you want to check, which I'm not clear what exactly that is.

Comment: @deceze Thank you very much for your answer. But your solution will be hard for me. I hope to find true regex codes for this check. Best regards,